# Process text file by C++ -- extract a certain string from text file

Tags: c++, string, getline, substr, strtok

I am a new learner to C++.
I have a text file, its contents like following:

```
Systemname    localtesthost
SystemIp      X.X.X.X
Systemowner   root
...
```

Now I want to extract **the value of "Systemname", that is "localtesthost".**

And I can extract the line containing "Systemname    localtesthost", but I don't know how to extract the String "Systemname".

Below is my program need help:

```
const char* configInfoFile = "config_info";//the text file name
ifstream ifs(configInfoFile);
    string line;
    while(getline(ifs,line)) {
        if(line.length() > 0){
            int index = line.find("SystemName");
            if (index != -1)
            {

                                .
                                .

            }

        } 
}
```

Could any one show me how to extract the string `"localtesthost"`?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an approach:

1. create a `std::istringstream` using the line you just read in.
2. read from the stream two `std::string` objects, key and value
3. if the key matches what you are looking for, value should contain what you require.

Comment: Nim, thanks to your method. It is much simple than I thought. Thanks!